# Modifying an input NSString value in a Objective-C method

Tags: objective-c, methods, nsstring, arguments

In terms of memory management, is it correct to modify the input variable `content` in the following method?

```
- (NSMutableArray *) extractResults:(NSString *)content {
  ...
  regex = [NSRegularExpression ...];
  content = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:content
                                            options:0
                                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [content length])
                                       withTemplate:@""];
  ...
}
```

In this particular case I do not care if the value remains modified outside the method scope. Just wondering if that assignment produces a memory leak.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't produce a leak because the return value of `stringByReplacing...` is autoreleased. However, you should be aware that you are not modifying the `content` object at all. `NSString` is immutable, so you can't do that, you're creating a new instance and assigning it to the variable.

Comment: And what about the old value of `content`? Is it released when the assignment takes place as if I were using a property-based setter? BTW, outside this method `content` is also an autoreleased `NSString`.

Comment: The old value is autoreleased, just as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

As `content` variable is your *local variable*, so it is correct. You only change memory address that is stored in variable `content`. Don't forget to release memory, that you pass in variable `content`.